# Show Date Created in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem

My teacher doesn't believe that I did my homework, just because I did like 95% of it.
So he thinks that I did it this morning and I want to prove to him that I did in fact do it last night @ 6 pm.

In other words, I would like to know how to check when a TextEdit document was created on Mac.
I am running El Capitan.

Comment: The file creation date is modifiable using `SetFile -d date` from the command line (at least through Yosemite but I'd be surprised if that was removed in El Capitan), and duplicating a file in the Finder sets the creation date of the copy to the creation date of the original, so the creation date doesn't offer any actual evidence as to when you did your homework.

Comment: Unless the teacher is ***really*** sharp, that will not be an issue ;)

Answer (score 5):

Set your Finder window to List View, then right click in the header bar where it says Name, Date Modified etc & check Date Created

[image]

Comment: And from the command line, `GetFileInfo -d <file>` will get the creation date and `SetFile -d <date> <file>` will set it.